# Text Responsive Issue in css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, sass

I have the following code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square .square-image img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square,
  .square1 {
    max-width: 460px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .h11 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

.containerE {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .containerE {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="containerE" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="square-image">
          <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details">
          <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
          <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="square1">
        <div class="square-image1">
          <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details1">
          <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
          <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

When you run the above code, open it on a new page, inspect it and view it on a 220 width screen, then you can see the text overflows outside the blog card.

I want to make the `.h11` and `p0` text to fit inside the blog card and not flow outside of it. I dont want to change the font size of both of them, but is there a way I can set the width to 100% so that the text doesn't overflow outside the blog card?

For some reason, the second blog card text is fine even on 220 width screen, but the first blog text is not. Any suggestions to make the `.h11` and `p0` text fit inside the blog card like the second blog card?

I even tried adding a media query and using `width: 100%` to `.h11` but it did not work.

Comment: It is happening due to the size of the words getting more than width of card. In second blog for 220px, it looks well as word are smaller. Reduce the width to 150px and you will see the issue happening on that as well. There is one [word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break) css property which should be able to help you here. It however will distort the text badly.

Comment: so why is the text working in second blog but not first blog?

Comment: It isn't. It appears that second blog is working but if you further reduce the width to 150px; the issue start to happen. Checkout this image: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XbRX.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XbRX.png) and you will see the issue happening for second blog also. Additionally, you can try changing the content in first block to `"Chances Of My Uni / College Admission ?"` and it will appear to work fine for 220px size.

Comment: ah so do you know how i can fix it?

Comment: You could use `word-break: break-all;` but you still have the same issue with your button. Why do you want to go as far as `220px` ?

Comment: I don't understand why you want to do this? what's the point of checking a 220px device width? It's normal and nothing to worry about but as others said you can use ``word-break: break-all;``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary to do this cause 220px is not a phone for humans maybe for cats. but you can use this simply In your CSS.

```
* { word-break: break-all; }
```

```css
* { word-break: break-all; }
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather|Open+Sans');
.square {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.square:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square .square-image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square .square-details {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.h11 {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: left;
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-size: 24px;
}

p0 {
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #C8C8C8;
  line-height: 18px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: block;
}

.button56 {
  background-color: #0563bb;
  color: white;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px 18px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-family: 'merriweather';
}

.button56:hover {
  opacity: 0.9;
  color: white;
}

.square1:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(20px, -10px);
  -ms-transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  transform: translate(10px, -10px);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}

.square1 .square-image1 img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 220px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  border-top-right-radius: 4px;
  border: 5px solid #555;
}

.square1 .square-details1 {
  padding: 20px 30px 30px;
}

.square1 {
  max-width: 460px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 20px #D9DBDF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 {
    margin-bottom: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 54px;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .square1 .square-image1 img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square .square-image img {
    height: 230px !important;
    border: 5px solid #555;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
  .square,
  .square1 {
    max-width: 460px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .h11 {
    width: 100% !important;
  }
}

.containerE {
  --bs-gutter-x: 1.5rem;
  width: 100%;
  padding-right: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  padding-left: calc(var(--bs-gutter-x) / 2);
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .containerE {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 20px;
    justify-content: center;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="section-title">
    <h2>Featured Blogs Of The Day</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
    <div class="containerE" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
      <div class="square">
        <div class="square-image">
          <img src="assets/img/Blog1.png">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details">
          <h3 class="h11">“Chances Of My Uni/College Admission?”</h3>
          <p0>It is that time of the year again (yay!) where we — high school students — are supposed to fill out the applications and land in our dream Universities/Colleges!</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/chances-of-my-uni-college-admission-20bc0efec0af" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="square1">
        <div class="square-image1">
          <img src="assets/img/Blog2.png">
        </div>

        <div class="square-details1">
          <h3 class="h11">My Career Advice To You: Take These Steps...</h3>
          <p0>Humans tend to make mistakes — and its completely normal as it results in the growth and development of an individual — either psychologically or physically.</p0>
          <div><a href="https://m-hussainomer03.medium.com/my-career-advice-to-you-take-these-steps-to-ultimate-prosperity-6c0687ce9c9f" target="_" class="button56">Read More</a></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```